# I would like to create a database with the goal of populating this database with comprehensive inventory information obtained via a shell script

Tags: mysql, database, bash, postgresql

I would like to create a database with the goal of populating this database with comprehensive inventory information obtained via a shell script from each client machine. My shell script currently writes this information to a single csv file located on a server through an ssh connection. Of course, if this script were to be run on multiple machines at once it would likely cause issues as each client potentially would try to write to the csv at the same time.

In the beginning, the inventory was all I was after; however after more thought I began to ponder wether or not much much more could be possible after I gathered this information. If I were to have this information contained within a database I might be able to utilize the information to initialize other processes based on the information of a specific machine or group of "like" machines. It is important to note that I am already currently managing a multitude of processes by identifying specific machine information. However pulling that information from a database after matching a unique identifier (in my mind) could greatly improve the efficiency. Also allowing for more of server side approach cutting down on the majority of client side scripting. (Instead of gathering this information from the client machine on the startup of each client I would have it already in a central database allowing a server to utilize the information and kick off specific events)

I am completely foreign to SQL and am not certain if it is 100% necessary. Is it necessary? For now I have decided to download and install both PostgreSQL and MySQL on separate Macs for testing. I am also fairly new to stackoverflow and apologize upfront if this is an inappropriate question or style of question. Any help including a redirection would be appreciated greatly.

I do not expect a step by step answer by any means, rather am just hoping for a generic "proceed..." "this indeed can be done..." or "don't bother there is a much easier solution."

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is too generic, community here can help you out on a specific issues you'll be facing.

Comment: Thanks. SO is already becoming a huge help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I come from the PostgreSQL world, I highly recommend using it for it's strong enterprise-level features and high standard compliance.

I always prefer to have a database for each project that I'm doing for the following benefits:

1. Normalized data is easier to process and build reports on;
2. Performance of database queries will be much better due to the caching done by the DB engine, indexes on your data, optimized query paths;
3. You can greatly improve machine data processing by using [`SQL/MED`](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL/MED), which allows querying external data sources from the database directly. You can have a look on the  [Multicorn project](http://multicorn.org/) and examples they provide.
4. Should it be required to deliver any kinds of reports to your management, DB will be your friend, while doing this outside the DB will be overly complicated.

Shortly — go for the database!

Comment: Thank you so much. As I proceed I am sure I will post additional questions. But for now, thanks to you I have a bearing and am off and running. Thanks again.

Comment: Next time ask specific technical questions and take generic decision yourself. Good luck!